# Отображение строк из файла С++

Tags: c++, файлы, вывод

Есть часть программы, читающая содержимое файла:

```
string data;  
ifstream fin(("/Users/Margarita/XCode/Full_As1/user_file.txt"));  
while (!fin.eof())  
{  
    getline (fin, data);  
    cout << data;
}  
fin.close();
```

В файле лежат целые числа - по одному в строке.

Нужно, чтобы на экран они также выводились по одному в строке, а у меня — «слипшиеся» в ряд.

Где поставить какой-нибудь `\n`?

Comment: Посмотрите в отладчике после какой строки у вас выводится очередное число, туда и ставьте /n

Comment: Ни в стандартной билиотеке языка С, ни в стандартной билиотеке  языка С++ циклы с предусловием `!eof` обычно не являются корректными. В С и С++ `eof` - это, по определению, условие завершения предыдущей операции ввода-вывода. Для завершения чтения проверяйте, что возвращает `getline`. Не пытайтесь использовать `eof` для этой цели.

Answer (score 4):

Напишите либо так

```
string data;

while ( getline( fin, data ) )
{
    cout << data  << endl;
}
```

либо так

```
string data;

while ( getline( fin, data ) )
{
    cout << data  << '\n';
}
```

либо так

```
string data;

while ( fin >> data )
{
    cout << data  << std::endl;
}
```

либо так

```
string data;

while ( fin >> data )
{
    cout << data  << '\n';
}
```

В последних двух случаях вы вообще можете использовать некоторый арифметический тип, который соответствует вводимым значениям.

Например,

```
int data;

while ( fin >> data )
{
    cout << data  << '\n';
}
```

Можно еще использовать алгоритм `std::copy`, объявленный в заголовке `<algorithm>`, вместо цикла `while`.

Например

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iterator>

//...

std::ifstream fin( "/Users/Margarita/XCode/Full_As1/user_file.txt" );

std::copy( std::istream_iterator<int>( fin ),
           std::istream_iterator<int>(),
           std::ostream_iterator<int>( std::cout, "\n" ) );
```

Имейте в виду, что ваш цикл на самом деле некорректный

```
 while (!fin.eof())  
 {  
     getline (fin,data);  
     cout<< data   
 }
```

Проблема в том, что состояние конца файла может наступить в момент выполнения предложения

```
     getline (fin,data);
```

В этом случае в строку `data` ничего не будет введено. Тем не менее вы ее выводите на консоль следующим предложением

```
     cout<< data
```

Эффект может быть таким, что последняя запись в файле будет выведена два раза.

Answer (score 0):

Реализовала так:

```
ifstream fin(("/Users/Margarita/XCode/Full_As1/user_file.txt"))  
int max_length = 10;  
char line[max_length];  
while (fin.getline(line, max_length))  
{  
     for (int j = 0; j < max_length; j++)  
     cout << line[j] << "\n" << endl;  
}  
fin.close();
```

Внешне работает так, как задумывалось, но поправьте, если снова не корректно.

Comment: Ваш код не имеет смысла, так как вы будете выводить на консоль всякий "мусор", если считанная строка меньше max_length.